# jasper.jar has no source attachment TagFileProcessor.class when using a JSP tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, tomcat7, taglib

I'm having a problem loading JSP tag within my JSP pages.

I include the taglibs like so:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
```

and include my tag in the page like so:

```
<tags:company-icons companyID="${company.id}" />
```

When I attempt to go to the page with this tag line in I get the following:

```
The JAR file /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/lib/jasper.jar has no source attachment.
You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below:
```

If I attach the jasper.jar I get the following:

```
The source attachment does not contain the source for the file TagFileProcessor.class.
```

I have unzipped the jasper.jar file and there is a `TagFileProcessor.class` file in there but no .java which should be fine.

This has been working fine for a number of months and suddenly stopped working with no explanation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed the following at the top of my tab:

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
```

Whereas I had:

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```